# Android: Detecting application backgrounding

Tags: android

I have an application that has many screens. Is it possible to detect if the screen NOT belonging to the application (not defined in my android manifest) comes into visibility?

Comment: What precisely is your goal? Normally, each of your activities should start going to sleep in onPause.

Answer (score 1):

`onPause()` will be called when an Activity loses focus (to any screen, be it your own or someone elses). When your user launches another activity from your app, you can set a flag when they do so and check for it in `onPause()`. If the flag isn't there, you can assume another app has gained focus.

Answer (score 0):

If it's something like go back to login screen, try to read about android:finishOnTaskLaunch

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#finish

It solved my similiar problem ;-)